# Getting the wrong record count on join rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Here are some relations for your consideration :

```
- User has one profile
- Profile belongs to user

- User has many favourites
```

I have some user ids and I want to get the profiles whos users have favourites.

Tried so many different queries that my head starts to spin, here are some :

```
    Profile.select('profiles.id')
    .joins("INNER JOIN users ON profiles.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN favourites 
    ON favourites.user_id = users.id")
    .where("users.id in (?)", some_ids)
```

I splitted the lines for easier readability.

Using this query regardless whether my user has got or hasn't got favourites I still get those profiles back.

This one results in the same result if I take out the duplicates :

```
Profile.joins(user: [:favourites]).where('users.id in (?) and favourites.user_id is not null', some_ids)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How many records are you getting compared to how many you are expecting?

Comment: Well I just one favourite to the user to test with one. And then I remove the one, but the first query returns the same result in both cases, regardless if user has a favourite or not

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
Profile.select('profiles.id')
    .joins(:favourites)
    .joins("LEFT JOIN users ON profiles.user_id = users.id AND favourites.user_id = users.id")
    .where("users.id in (?)", some_ids)
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, the result is just the same with my query

Comment: I know ..it may sound silly ..but can try with LEFT join instead INNNER join.

Comment: it does not sound sily, but still the same result

Comment: I think a work around will be to first load all users with favourites and then find profile for that users